# shared_preferences values returning null in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I am using shared_preferences to store a bool value locally but I think I am doing something wrong.
So first of all, here is my initState:

```
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    checkIfUserHasData();
    getBoolValuesSF();
}
```

on checkIfUserHasData, Im calling another function at the end (addBoolToSF)

```
 Future<void> checkIfUserHasData  ()async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.
    collection('users').doc(userID).collection('personalInfo');
    var querySnapshots = await collection.get();
    for (var snapshot in querySnapshots.docs) {
      documentID = snapshot.id;
    }
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userID)
        .collection('personalInfo').doc(documentID)
        .get().then((value) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(()  {
        gender = value.get('gender');
        profileImageUrl = value.get('url');
        print(profileImageUrl);
   
        print(gender);
      });
    });
    if (gender != null){
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState((){
        isUserNew = false;
      });
      if(gender == "Male"){
        setState(() => genderIsMale = true);
        addBoolToSF();



      }else{
        setState(() => genderIsMale = false);
        addBoolToSF();

      }
    }else {
      return;
    }

  }
```

Then addBoolToSF:

```
addBoolToSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('genderType', genderIsMale);
  }
```

Lastely getBoolValuesSF:

```
getBoolValuesSF() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

   setState(() {
     bool _genderType = ((prefs.getBool('genderType') ?? true)) ;
     genderType = _genderType;
   });
 }
```

When the genderType value is obtained I then decide which image to be the background image on the screen:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
            placeholder: (context, url) =>
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
            imageUrl: genderType ? // : //
```

With all of that said, here is what is happening when the gender is changed on the firebase firestore:
The first time I navigate or refresh the screen nothing is changed and I get this error:

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

The second time I refresh or navigate to the screen, I do get the correct image on place but I get the same error message again

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

I have tried several ways to solve this issue but i dont seem to get it right.

Edit: I have noticed that when I removed the last part for CachedNetworkImage, I get no error so I think the problem might be on this part

Comment: Shouldn't you await the call of checkIfUserHasData before doing getBoolValuesSF?

Comment: @VincentDR I guess that make sense but I cant await inside initState. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: There is not just a single problem in your code..., There are many 

Comment: @UsamaKarim well, I will appreciate it if you mention some so I can improve it instead of just saying this :)

Comment: Have you set any default value to `genderType`? If not then set it either `false` or `true`

Comment: @UsamaKarim First of all, Thank you for your useful comment. I have declared genderType as var initially but as after your comment I changed it to bool and gave it initial value. The error message is gone, however, I still have the screen image problem. When the genderType value changes, The image doesnt change until refreshing the page twice

Comment: @UsamaKarim I tried to add set state after getBoolValueSF is finished on the initState : getBoolValuesSF().then((_genderType) {
     
      setState(() {
        genderType = _genderType;
      });

Comment: If you need to await the result of `getBoolValuesSF` to build your UI, using a `FutureBuilder` seems a good way of doing this, instead of putting this in the initState

Comment: @PierreMonier Thanks! this was actually very helpful

Comment: I will write an answer if you think it was what you wanted

Comment: You are getting data from a nested collection from Firebase. Then you are using `for loop` on that data and doing nothing inside it. Which doesn't make sense to me. To get an idea of what's happening inside `for loop` is setting the ID of last snapshot which you can directly access through `querySnapshots.docs.last` and no need to use `for loop`. Now the question is if you always only need ID of last document then why are you fetching the whole collection, this way you are using user resources and increasing reading cost, and you can easily access last Document by using queries in Firebase.

Comment: The second tip is when you are already getting whole collection anyway then why are you fetching a single document from inside the collection you already have access to.

Comment: Third tip: When you have access to online database and still you are saving and then instantly accessing to offline database, it's nowhere a good solution. You can save the object to offline database but access it when you don't have access to online database only or don't want to access it from offline database. While you have access to the object from online database, use the same object to refresh your screen. I hope it will make it all clear. Make decisions wisely.

Comment: @UsamaKarim Thanks brother, I appreciate the time you spent writing these useful tips. But I just have some comments. First of all regarding the for loop, I didnt actually know that I can obtain the Id in a way like what you did. I removed that for loop and my current code is like this: documentID = querySnapshots.docs.last.id;. 

Then regarding your question why am I fetching the whole collection when I need only the last doc. Firstly, the collection will always have 1 doc anyway so I dont think its using more resources if I fetch the whole collection (please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Secondly, I am literally using all the data values stored iside this doc in different functions, however, what I am planning to do is to use shared preferences to store the key values which I will always need locally and then everytime I need to use one of these values I will check first if they are stored locally and only if not then I go and make a request to the DB.

Comment: @UsamaKarim Finally, I wanna thank you for your useful tips and suggestions which I do appreciate highly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case like that when you need to wait for a future to build some UI, the go to way is to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

You use it like this

```dart
FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: getBoolValuesSF,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          // build your UI here based on snapshot value
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

`checkIfUserHasData()` and `getBoolValuesSF()` both are future method. you can create another async method and put it inside initState.

```dart
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    newMthod();
}


newMthod() async{
await checkIfUserHasData();
await getBoolValuesSF();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. that make a lot of sense